# Documentation: add short summary to topics

Tags: feature-request, documentation

On individual topic listings, like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/topics

A short (max. 250 character) summary would be really helpful to describe what each sub-topic is. In many cases it's just not clear form the title.

For example under the the GIT / Squash headline it could say that `With git it's possible to squash previous commits into one.`

If I don't know what squashing means, I might just skip it.

Even if I click on quashing, the top comment doesn't address what squashing is:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/598/squashing#t=201607251301425042526

Comment: Great idea; I like it! This could be in the "title" section of the editor.

Comment: These are not really duplicates however covering the same thing. I'd like to see the topic listing page enhanced.